# Throughout aviation history, what airships were metal clad?

Tags: airship

Throughout aviation history, what airships were built with metal skin instead of fabric or other material?

Comment: There was a wooden airship. Everyone was very excited about it, but it wooden fly.

Comment: @Richard: If I were you I wooden tell that joke anymore.

Comment: @FredLarson - I should leaf now before I tell acorny joke.

Comment: @Richard: I saw what you did there, and it really goes against the grain. But I think your bark is worse than your bite.

Comment: @FredLarson - We should stop this now before the moderators take a fence.

Comment: @Richard: Agreed, because [Stack Exchange hates fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284390/145136). But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least two all-metal airships are known to have existed, the first one invented by David Schwarz, and test-flown in Tempelhof, in 1897. It flew, but crashed when landing.

Another one, a really successful and better known aircraft, was an American airship, the ZMC-2, that first flew in 1929.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Schwarz_(aviation_inventor)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMC-2

Answer (score 3):

There is a metal airship currently being built by an Englishman in France, called the VariaLift. https://www.varialift.com/

[image]

The specifications are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Maybe you could include an image and a couple more details about it?

Comment: "*metal airship currently being built by an Englishman*". While it was expected the first prototype should have been ready last summer, it seems they are still [building the hangar](https://www.varialift.com/page/news-events).

Comment: It doesnt need a hangar. If youre looking at photos of a hangar shaped structure - thats the airship frame - the build it outdoors in sections on a production line. Theres no hangar, just assembly sheds and they are old WW2 buildings which are still in place.

Answer (score 3):

There was no stipulation on whether the airship had to carry anybody. This [Myth Buster experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZSkM-QEeUg) successfully flew a very large LEAD balloon (30-50ft dia).

[image]